# Devise invitable sending user to root route instead of invitation page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

I want to implement Devise Invitable into my app, however, It isn't working as expected. Right now The email sends correctly, but when the user clicks on the `accept invitation` link, they don't get sent to a page where they can set their password, they get sent to the root route of the website. What's even weirder is that when I inspect the `accept invite` link, the hyper reference is set to 
`http://localhost:3000/users/invitation/accept?invitation_token=aQ9_9eubcMHv-hXuUM3T"`

That is what is supposed to be set to! But it's not sending me there. It seems as though once the users does arrive to the page, Devise Invitable automatically redirects the user to the home page instead of rendering the form which allows the user to set their password, and I have no idea why

here is my invitations controller

```
class Users::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController 
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters

  protected 
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:accept_invitation, keys: [:first_name, :last_name])
  end
end
```

and here are my routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, controllers: { invitations: 'users/invitations' }
  root 'pages#home'

  get '/dashboard', to: 'dashboard#index'
  namespace :dashboard do
    resources :projects do 
      post :toggle_status
    end
    resources :users, except: [:edit, :update]
  end
end
```

Here is what my logs report as soon as I click the accept link:

```
Started GET "/users/invitation/accept?invitation_token=nXxxSxP8vC3yUogm9yzx" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-08-26 21:33:37 -0600
Processing by Users::InvitationsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"invitation_token"=>"nXxxSxP8vC3yUogm9yzx"}
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."invitation_token" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["invitation_token", "a807392954389f3dd2054bfe03567b5419d6da7212f1c490ee2b46a9641037a6"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/angelgarcia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 20], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/angelgarcia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-08-26 21:33:37 -0600
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
  Rendering pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 83ms (Views: 76.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Here are my routes for Devise

```
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                                                                  devise_invitable/registrations#cancel
          new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                                                                 devise_invitable/registrations#new
         edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                                                                    devise_invitable/registrations#edit
              user_registration PATCH  /users(.:format)                                                                         devise_invitable/registrations#update
                                PUT    /users(.:format)                                                                         devise_invitable/registrations#update
                                DELETE /users(.:format)                                                                         devise_invitable/registrations#destroy
                                POST   /users(.:format)                                                                         devise_invitable/registrations#create
         accept_user_invitation GET    /users/invitation/accept(.:format)                                                       users/invitations#edit
         remove_user_invitation GET    /users/invitation/remove(.:format)                                                       users/invitations#destroy
            new_user_invitation GET    /users/invitation/new(.:format)                                                          users/invitations#new
                user_invitation PATCH  /users/invitation(.:format)                                                              users/invitations#update
                                PUT    /users/invitation(.:format)                                                              users/invitations#update
                                POST   /users/invitation(.:format)                                                              users/invitations#create
```

Comment: In the logs, when you click the link, which `controller` and `action` is being triggered? Also, are you getting any warning/errors ? Which action is going to handle the `accept` request ?

Comment: Ok, I just provided logs

Comment: Where have you defined `after_invite_path_for` ?

Comment: Can you update your OP with the `edit` action ?

Comment: I haven't defined that path. Or at least I don't think I did. Would devise invitable have defined that path? Let me provide my routes

Comment: I suppose I could update my `edit` action, but I wouldn't know what to put in it. It doesn't say anything about the edit action in the documentation. I'm just letting devise invitable take care of that. Unless there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Have you generated `views` using this ? `rails generate devise_invitable:views`

Comment: When you click the link right in the email, you want the user's invite to be `accepted` ?

Comment: Yes i have. I have ran this `rails generate devise_invitable:views users`

Comment: And I want their invite to be accepted only after they set their password and submit invitation form

Comment: Read this [section](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable#integration-in-a-rails-application) and I have overridden this method `after_accept_path_for(resource)`

Comment: What you could is - When the user clicks the link, it is redirecting him to `edit` action, you can also set the resource's invitation token here using `resource.invitation_token = params[:invitation_token]` and render `edit` , create a view for `edit` with `password` and `password_confirmation` fields. Once the user enters those, call `update` action and redirect him to `profiles_path`(just an example path, change to where you want to redirect) using `after_accept_path_for(resource)`

Comment: Yes, I do the views for the `edit` action with passwords fields. But, still, the user is being redirected to root route after clicking the accept link

Comment: Are you `signed in` with `another account`, when you're clicking the link in the email ?

Comment: omg yes I am, let me try without it.

Comment: Yes it worked, thank you so much! I feel so dumb lol.

Answer (score 0):

Override the default path by using after_invite_path_for method

```
class InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController

  def after_invite_path_for(resource)
   #your_path
   new_admin_user_invitation_url
  end
end
```